# div showing shadow default

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a problem with. div scrollbar.
I applied scroll bar to div.
But is showing the scrollbar(both horizental and vartical) showdow intially.
But I should show scroll bar when div has overflow.
my code is

```
<td class="style4">
       <div style="margin-top:-6px; overflow:scroll;height:120px;">
       <asp:Repeater ID="dispatureRepeater" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <table class="dispatchTable">
       <tr>
       <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Name" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server"/> 
        </td> 
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="regCalLbl" Text='<%# Eval("Regular") %>' runat="server"/>
        </td>
        <td >
        <asp:Label ID="emergclbl" Text='<%# Eval("Emergency") %>' runat="server"/>
        </td>
        <td >
        <asp:Label ID="directCalLbl" Text='<%# Eval("DirectCal") %>' runat="server"/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="totLbl" Text='<%# Eval("Total") %>' runat="server"/>
        </td>
        </tr>  
        </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        </td>
```

please help me.

Comment: Your code hasn't formatted correctly, perhaps you could retry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `<div>` style, use `overflow: auto` instead of `overflow: scroll`.

[Overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)